# is insert() necessary in a map or unordered_map?

Tags: c++

I see a lot of examples that add items to a `map` or `unordered_map` via  `operator[]`, like so:

```
int main() {
    unordered_map <string, int> m;
    m["foo"] = 42;
    cout << m["foo"] << endl;
}
```

Is there any reason to use the `insert` member function instead? It would appear they both do the same thing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are not.

`operator[]` will overwrite the value for this key, if it exists, while `insert` will not.

In case `operator[]` is used for inserting element, it is expected to be a little slower (see @MatthieuM's comment below for details), but this is not that significant here.

While `std::map::insert` returns `std::pair< iterator, bool >`, where the `.second` will tell you if the value is inserted or it already exists.

---

Regarding your comment: you cannot have 2 elements with the same key and different value. This is not a `multimap`.

If there's an element in the map, with the same key you're trying to insert, then:

- `operator[]` will overwrite the existing value
- `std::map::insert` will <strike>not do anything.</strike><sup>*</sup> return a `std::pair< iterator, bool >`, where the `.second` will be `false` (saying "the new element is not inserted, as such key already exists") and the `.first` will point to the found element.

<sub><sup>*</sup> I changed this thanks to the note/remark, given from @luk32; but by writing "will not do anything", I didn't mean it literally, I meant that it will not change the value of the existing element</sub>

Comment: Ok, so what happens if you insert two items with the same key?

Comment: The data for that key will not be overwritten. The bracket notation is equivalent to `(*((m.insert(value_type(k, data_type()))).first)).second = data;` (borrowed from footnote 3 [here](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html)). Which is to say, it inserts the key with a default-constructed datum, then takes the iterator returned (the `.first`), which either points to the old, unmodified key-value pair, if it existed, or to the new one just added, and sets the data (the `.second`) associated with the key to your desired value.

Comment: `operator[]` will not do anything either. `T::operator=` Using the reference from obtained from `map::operator[]` will do. And you can obtain the same reference using `insert()`. It is down to strict semantic analysis. But I think I am right here, while I still understand your more human-like approach, where it does seem that they behave differently. But when you break down the code, they are not. It's just more stuff happens here `mymap["answer"]=42` than it seems. At least to my feeling.

Comment: @KirilKirov: `operator[]` is expected to be a little slower, but I would not say it is because of the check; both `operator[]` and `insert` perform the same number of checks. `operator[]` is slower for straight insertion because it first builds a default value *and then* use assignment to overwrite it.

Comment: @MatthieuM. - ooh, right, right, my bad. You're damn right, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Using `insert()` can help improve performance in certain situations (more specifically for `std::map` since search time is `O(log(n))` instead of constant amortized).  Take the following common example:

```
std::map<int, int> stuff;

// stuff is populated, possibly large:

auto iterator = stuff.find(27);

if(stuff.end() != iterator)
{
   // subsequent "find", set to 15
   iterator->second = 15;
}
else
{
   // insert with value of 10
   stuff[27] = 10;
}
```

The code above resulted in effectively finding the element twice.  We can make that (slightly) more efficient written like this:

```
// try to insert 27 -> 10
auto result = stuff.insert(std::make_pair(27, 10));

// already existed
if(false == result.second)
{
   // update to 15, already exists
   result.first->second = 15;
}
```

The code above only tries to find an element once, reducing algorithmic complexity.  For frequent operations, this can improve performance drastically.

Answer (score 2):

The two are not equivalent.  `insert` will not overwrite an existing value, and it returns a `pair<iterator, bool>`, where `iterator` is the location of the key, regardless of whether or not it already existed. The `bool` indicates whether or not the insert occurred.

`operator[]` effectively does a `lower_bound` on key. If the result of that operation is an `iterator` with the same key, it returns a reference to the value. If not, it inserts a new node with a default-constructed value, and then returns a reference to the value. This is why `operator[]` is a non-const member - it auto-vivifies the key-value if it doesn't exist.  **This may have performance implications if the value type is costly to construct.**

Also note in C++11, we have an `emplace` method that works nearly identical to `insert`, except it constructs the key-value pair in-place from forwarded arguments, if an insert occurs.

Comment: the note about emplace is particularly important, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well I disagree with Kiril's answer to a certain degree and I think it's not full so I give mine.

According to [`cppreference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) `std::map::operator[]` is equivalent to a certain `insert()` call. By this I also think he is wrong saying the value will be overwritten.
It says: "Return value
Reference to the mapped value of the new element if no element with key key existed. Otherwise a reference to the mapped value of the existing element is returned."

So it seems it is a convenient wrapper. The `insert()`, however has this advantage of being overloaded, so it provides more functionality under one name.

I give a point to Kiril, that they do seem to have a bit different functionality at first glance, however IHMO the examples he provides are not equivalent to each other.

Therefore, as an example/reason to use `insert` I would point out, inserting many elements at once, or using `hint` ( Calls 3-6 in [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert)).

**So is insert() necessary in a map or unordered_map?**
I would say yes. Moreover, the `operator[]` is not necessary as it can be emulated/implemented using `insert`, while the other way is impossible! It simply provides more functinality. However, writing stuff like `(insert(std::make_pair(key, T())).first)->second)` (after [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at)) seems cumbersome than `[]`.

**Thus, is there any reason to use the insert member function instead?**
I'd say for overlapping functionality, hell no.

Comment: I agree, but returning a reference and using this code `m["foo"] = 42` (from the question) actually overwrites the value of `foo` if it existed before this call, right? Also, I don't say, that one of these `insert` or `operator[]` are better. Each of them has their own advantages (I'm saying this because of your note for the overloaded range `insert`). What I mean is - they can be used differently, but the OP asked for a specific case. +1 anyway, good points.

Comment: OK, it will effectively overwrite it. That's why I said I disagree to a certain degree. Still I am not sure if you can say it is entirely different, as you can implement `operator[]` with `insert()`. I'd say your 2nd part of answer is murky to say the least. `m["foo"]` will do nothing. Just as `*(insert("foo")->first) = 42` will update value, and this is the equivalent to your example. I think you confused two things. But I understand your point as well.

Comment: I never said, that `operator[]` cannot be implemented using `insert`. If you're talking about my words "will not do anything" - OK, I agree that it's not exactly "nothing", but I didn't mean it _literally_. OK, I'll edit it and I'll give you a reference, as it could be misunderstood badly.